# Set the size of radio buttons styled horizontally , that suit for all screen sizes

Tags: android, radio-button

In my android app, i have three radio buttons that are styled horizontally like this,

[image]

The problem is that, when i run my app on an android phone that has small screen, one of the radio button falls down from the line. How can i set a specific size for these radio text so they can adjust according to mobile screen?

This is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/remedy1">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/selection"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Sensation"
                android:id="@+id/sens" android:checked="true"
                android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/loc" android:checked="false"
                android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Modalation"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/mod" android:checked="false"
                android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/>
    </RadioGroup>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happen because you provide only one layout for all screensizes and density !

What can you do?

Create in your res folder of your project:

```
res-small
res-medium
res-large...
```

And put your customized layouts in.

This will provide the best layout experience for your users and android will choose the best layout for the specific device! Hope it helps!

Read more about
 http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html